# Handling onTouch and onClick events properly in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using following code to drag a View across the screen

```
   tweatBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            float currX,currY;

            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action ) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    mPrevX = event.getRawX();
                    mPrevY = event.getRawY();

                    btnPrevX = tweatBtn.getX();
                    btnPrevY = tweatBtn.getY();

                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    int width  = display.getWidth() + 80;  // deprecated
                    int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated

                    currX = event.getRawX();
                    currY = event.getRawY();
                    if(tweatBtn.getY() > 80 && tweatBtn.getX() > 0 && tweatBtn.getX() < width)
                    {
                        tweatBtn.setX(btnPrevX + currX - mPrevX);
                        tweatBtn.setY(btnPrevY + currY - mPrevY);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if((btnPrevY + currY - mPrevY) > 70 && (btnPrevX + currX - mPrevX) > -10 && tweatBtn.getX() < (width - 10))
                        {
                            tweatBtn.setX(btnPrevX + currX - mPrevX);
                            tweatBtn.setY(btnPrevY + currY - mPrevY);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

It works fine but sometimes when i lift the Finger it automatically triggers click.How can i improve?

Comment: return true if the event was consumed. replace "break" by "return true".

Comment: replace true and click will never fire again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning always `false` at the end of the code. Which means the touchListener you have set is not handling the touch. Because of if it, View will consider any normal touch as click. What you should do is `return True`, when the view is dragged, else you should `return False`

```
 boolean dragged = false;
 ViewConfiguration viewConfiguration = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
 int minTouchSlop = viewConfiguration.getScaledTouchSlop();

 .....

 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        float currX,currY;

        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action ) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                mPrevX = event.getRawX();
                mPrevY = event.getRawY();

                btnPrevX = tweatBtn.getX();
                btnPrevY = tweatBtn.getY();

                dragged = false; // global dragged variable

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                int width  = display.getWidth() + 80;  // deprecated
                int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated

                currX = event.getRawX();
                currY = event.getRawY();

                if(Math.abs(currX-mPrevX) > minTouchSlop || Math.abs(currY-mPrevY) > minTouchSlop)
                     dragged = true; // differntiate btw drag or click


                if(tweatBtn.getY() > 80 && tweatBtn.getX() > 0 && tweatBtn.getX() < width)
                {
                    tweatBtn.setX(btnPrevX + currX - mPrevX);
                    tweatBtn.setY(btnPrevY + currY - mPrevY);
                }
                else
                {
                    if((btnPrevY + currY - mPrevY) > 70 && (btnPrevX + currX - mPrevX) > -10 && tweatBtn.getX() < (width - 10))
                    {
                        tweatBtn.setX(btnPrevX + currX - mPrevX);
                        tweatBtn.setY(btnPrevY + currY - mPrevY);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
        }
        return dragged;
    }
```

Comment: there is a little setback with this code. it usually gives approx 1 second delay what should i do

Comment: What is getting delayed ?

Comment: The opening of new Activity. Let's say i click now, it will take 1-1.5 seconds for the app to open the new activity that is to call OnClickEvent. Also the button moves first few pixels away first

Comment: Reasons (1) Delay, because you are overriding onTouchListener, instead you should write custom btn/view(class extending btn/view) and should override `onTouchEvent()` and perform above logic. Listeners are like redirectors.   (2) Icon movement during click: Perform setX and setY only if `if(Math.abs(currX-mPrevX) > minTouchSlop || Math.abs(currY-mPrevY) > minTouchSlop)` else do nothing